# Separate .muttrc into parts

Tags: configuration, mutt

My `.muttrc` file is starting to get quite large.

What I would prefer is to create a `~/.mutt/config` directory to store various 
config files for the account, status bar, composition,... etc and then source them all into my main `.muttrc` file.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a folder `~/.mutt`
2. Split up your configuration in your folder
3. `source` all the config files in your folder, i.e. (from my `~/.mutt/muttrc`):

.

```
source ~/.mutt/rc
source ~/.mutt/hooks
source ~/.mutt/macros
source ~/.mutt/ml
source ~/.mutt/gnupg
```